# Angular2 Allow Components and its Sub Components to access single instance of ngModel in service

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ngmodel

I am building complex view with a lot of functionality on it. To keep things organized, I have broken it up into several custom components.

I'll try to keep this brief as I do have it working but I cant imagine that its the "right way".

Structure:

```
- AppComponent(has binding to dataModel)
--LayoutComponent
---HeaderComponent
---SideMenuComponent
---MainContentComponent
```

I need to be able to give each of these components access the same single instance of the data model. But when I add the service as a provider and to the constructor in each Component, it generates a new instance of the data. So edits done in one component, don't reflect in the data of a different one.

So what I did was give the top most parent `AppComponent` component access to the dataModel and then passed it down the chain through the template `[(dataModel)]="dataModel"`.

Then in each Component I added a `dataModel` variable which starts off as null, but after I build my template, I bind it to that local variable.

This works as I can bind inputs in each component to the same field i.e. dataModel.name and when I update it, all components reflect the change.

This just doesn't seem like a clean way of doing it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This seems more like a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) thing. Also as you only give us your structure, most of your tags don't apply.

Comment: Before rc5, you can just give the service to the parent component's provider and you can access the same instance of that service everywhere underneath it. From rc5 to final, you can add the service to the `AppModule` to make it singleton across the application.

Comment: @HarryNinh ok, I have not tried that. If I add it to AppModule would I still add it to my constructor in sub components like (datamodelservice:DataModelService)?

Comment: Yup, you still need to add it to your constructor (to have a reference to the service's instance).

Comment: That worked. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the service to providers of every component, every component gets its own service instance. Angular2 DI maintains a single instance per provider.

If you add it to providers of a comment ancestor, then this component and all descendants get an instance from this provider.

In >= RC.5 if you add the service to `providers: [...]` of any `@NgModule(...)` that is **not lazy loaded** it will be added as provider to the root injector and therefore shared with the whole application (as long as any of the descendant components also has it as provider which overrides it for its descendants).

For lazy loaded modules providers are shared within this lazy loaded module because lazy loaded modules have their own DI child scope.

Comment: Good explanation.